# what is wrong with these cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, isset

```
 <?php
include "some.php";//that s for mysql_connect
session_start();
$uid=$_REQUEST['uid'];
//main blocking
if(isset($_COOKIE['mainblocking'])){echo '1';}else{echo '2';}
....
```

everytime it throws 2;i set the cookie with that php file

```
<?php
setcookie("mainblocking", "1", time()+3600) or die("yeah");
?>
```

can anybody tell me what s wrong with this code and what is the lack of my knowledge 
by the way interesting thing is it throws 1 in that one

```
<?php
   if(isset($_COOKIE['mainblocking'])){echo '1';}else{echo 2;}
?>
```

Comment: Be sure to set the PATH and DOMAIN of a cookie if you want it to stick.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a path for your cookie like so:

```
setcookie("mainblocking", "1", "/", time()+3600)
```